# How to pick the date using date picker in dynamic table?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

My problem is how to use date picker in dynamic rows of the column.
I have used date picker in input text field,but it appears only in first row of the date column.
By selecting the date the date is not selected.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb3">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Bank Name</th>
                                    <th>Chq No</th>
                                    <th>Chq Date</th>
                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr >
                                    <td><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='remove3'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a></td>
<td>

                                    <input style="width:100px" type="text" id="Product_Code"  class="form-control input-xs Product_Code "name="name[]"></td>

                                    <td ><input style="width:100px" type="text" id="Product_Name" class="form-control input-xs" name = "no[]"   > </td>


                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control input-xs datepicker-dates" placeholder="Pick a date&hellip;" id="TDate" name="TDate" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y') ?>"</td>

                                    <td><input style="width:80px" type="text" id="Rate"  class="form-control input-xs" value="" name="rate[]"></td>

                                    <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" id="addMore3" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></td>



                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

This is table code...........

```
    <script>
$(function(){
    $('#addMore3').on('click', function() {
              var data = $("#tb3 tr:eq(1)").clone(true).appendTo("#tb3");
              data.find("input").val('');
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.remove3', function() {
         var trIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
            if(trIndex>0) {
             $(this).closest("tr").remove();
           } else {
             alert("Sorry!! Can't remove first row!");
           }
      });
});      
</script>
```

This is javascript code for creating dynamic rows and columns.

Comment: If you don't need any fancy date pickers just use input type as date

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<input type="text"  name="TDate" class="form-control" value="" id="datepicker">     
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker();
    });</script>
```

Comment: it is not available for second row

Comment: @Teddy id is a unique attribute. You can use the class to get date picker on all inputs

Comment: it does not pick the date

Comment: for class use  $('.datepicker').datepicker(); and use datepicker plugin in your header

Comment: @PHPGeek i have tired in class,but it is working in the first row only